# Custom widgets do not appear in dashboard > appearance > widgets

Tags: widgets

I recently moved my wp site from localhost to the web and lost all my widgets.

When I browse to Appeareance > Widgets in the wp dashboard I see the default widgets but not my custom widgets.

My widgets are declared in separate php files under mytheme/widgets. They are registered with the following code:

in myWidget.php:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() { register_widget( 'myWidget' ); } );
```

in theme/functions.php:

```
$widgets = glob(get_template_directory().'/widgets/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($widgets as $widget) {
    $className =  str_replace('.php', '', basename($widget) );
    include $widget;
}
```

I am new to web development and am having a hard time to identify and fix the issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work locally, but not on live site?

Comment: Yes it works fine on localhost.

Comment: Maybe the glob function is not working on your host? have you tried to dump $widgets in your code to see what it returns?

Comment: I tried that just now. It turns out that GLOB_BRACE was not recognized. I removed it and the widgets are back.
My problem seems simple and silly now but thank you so much for your help ^^

Comment: Remember to put that as an answer and accept it :) you're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

The glob function is not supporting GLOB_BRACE on the host.
The code in functions.php can be replaced by

```
$widgets = glob(get_template_directory().'/widgets/*.php');
foreach ($widgets as $widget) {
    $className =  str_replace('.php', '', basename($widget) );
    include $widget;
}
```

to fix the issue.